# Why is '302' not defined in Response.Status of javax.ws.rs?

Tags: java, http-response-codes

I'm trying to use a Java library to validate the universe of possible HTTP Responses, rather than writing my own logic to check each response code individually.

I've found a static class `Response.Status` in [javax.ws.rs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.html) which seems to perfectly fit this purpose.  Its documentation states:

> Commonly used status codes defined by HTTP, see HTTP/1.1 documentation
>   for the complete list.

If you visit the [link to the HTTP/1.1 docs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10), referenced by the javax documentation, clearly you see the `302` response status code as being valid.

However, the following call returns `null`, meaning that "the matching Status or null is no matching Status is defined" - which is obviously incorrect:

```
 Response.Status.fromStatusCode(302);
```

And sure enough, `302`/`FOUND` is not in the enumeration defined in this class.

Does anyone have any idea why this is?  Is it an oversight in the `javax.ws.rs` code - or was this done intentionally?

Comment: I suppose they didn't regard 302 as "commonly used".

Comment: @HotLicks that's crazy talk (by them, not you).  302 is probably one of the more ubiquitously found status codes - it's used for redirects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The enum value [`Response.Status.FOUND`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.html#FOUND) (302) was added in 2.0 (along with several other response codes missing from earlier versions).

Comment: At the risk of looking stupid, how do I use version 2.0 of javax.ws.rs?  I'm developing in Eclipse with an Oracle 7 JDK and it is still failing on the check I'm doing in the OP.

Comment: @jtravaglini - You are probably using a mix of J2SE 7 and J2EE 1.6. You need to separately [download J2EE 1.7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-7-downloads-1956236.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few status codes not covered by that enum. It seems clear they don't consider `302` "common" enough to be included by name.

Comment: Considering the mere minutes of typing required to provide the full set, it is crazy for it to be incomplete.

Comment: I said the same thing -- it's mysterious why this wasn't in 1.0.  Especially for 302.